Navigate through device's folders via ADB
I have connected and verified ADB on my phone:
adb start-server
adb devices

And then I wanted to go to DCIM folder in my storage to see, if there are any pictures to fetch.
However this has failed:
adb shell ls
adb shell cd /storage
adb shell pwd
adb shell ls

The second ls again shows root and pwd responds with /, not with /storage.
Tried storage and /storage, tried /sdcard and sdcard, assuming that storage might not be accessible for me. Tried /sdcard/DCIM and others, all for nothing.
I have Realme 50 GT with Android 14. What am I missing?

The problem
Each time you go adb shell <command>, you start a shell on the 'phone which does  <command> and then terminates. The context of what you're doing is lost, so each new shell starts with / as the default directory. That's why it looks as if you can't get into storage.
There are (at least) two ways to do what you're attempting:
Separate shell commands with semi-colons:
You would do your example commands like this:
adb shell "ls ; cd /storage ; pwd ; ls" 

You need double-quotes around the list of commands for the device so that your computer doesn't try to interpret them, which gets confusing fast.
Use the device shell directly
Here, I'm using A$ as the Android prompt, and C$ as your computer's prompt:
C$ adb shell
A$ ls
<list of the files and directories in your device's / folder>
A$ cd /storage
A$ pwd
/storage
A$ ls 
<list of the files and directories in your device's /storage folder>
A$ exit
C$ 

You need to learn about using command lines
Trying to use adb shell commands without understanding them will get frustrating quite quickly. Using a command line isn't hard, but it is rather different from using a graphical user interface ("GUI").
